# Get Vaadin Grid column by its id

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Using Vaadin 24 i want to get the `Grid.Column` object by its id as set by `Column#setId(String)`.

This, because i am using an `GridContextMenuOpenedEvent` and this event only gives me the column id.

There is a `Grid#getColumnByKey(String)` but no `Grid#getColumnById(String)`

```
menu.addGridContextMenuOpenedListener(e -> {
  // does not work key != id
  LOG.info(e.getColumnId().map(s -> grid.getColumnByKey(s)).map(c -> c.getHeaderText()).orElse("??"));
});
```

This is confusing for me. What is the **exact** difference / application for `id` versus `key`?

Making it more confusing: there is a `Grid#getColumnByInternalId()` method. However, it is private package and it seems that id are used mostly internally.
So, for the public API it seems to me that you should use keys, but the `GridContextMenuOpenedEvent` gives me the id??

### Bonus: ChatGPT "answer"

In Vaadin 24, the concept of "id" and "key" in Grid columns might be a bit confusing, and it appears that there is some inconsistency in the API regarding these terms. Let's clarify the differences between "id" and "key":

1. Column Key (Grid.Column#setKey(String)): This is a user-defined key that you can assign to a Grid column. It's meant to be a unique identifier for the column within the Grid. You can use Grid#getColumnByKey(String) to retrieve a column by its key. This key is often used for programmatic access to columns because it's user-defined and straightforward to work with.
2. Column Id (Grid.Column#setId(String)): This is an internal identifier used by Vaadin for managing the column. It's not meant to be used directly by application developers for accessing columns. The GridContextMenuOpenedEvent giving you the column ID is likely an internal detail of the event system, and it might not be the same as the user-defined key. This can indeed be confusing, as you've noted.
3. Grid#getColumnByInternalId(): As you mentioned, this method is private, and it's meant for internal use by Vaadin. It's not part of the public API and should not be used in your application code.

Given this information, you should ideally use the user-defined column keys (Grid.Column#setKey(String)) when you need to access columns programmatically. Unfortunately, if the GridContextMenuOpenedEvent provides the column ID instead of the key, you might need to manage a mapping between column IDs and keys yourself to look up columns based on the ID received in the event.

Comment: So, we are playing Jeopardy now?  What's the point of adding your answer
to the question?

Comment: No, for sure not. It just confirm my assumption. But i assume i miss something, because (as stated) GridContextMenuOpenedEvent **only** exposes the id. Or it is a bug. So maybe create a ticket at Vaadin instead of this question

Comment: The API design is not the best possible. Check this issue. The given workaround however is able to match columb with id https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1939